# Execute the same action for a set of routes in all components

Tags: angular, angular-router

Lets say I create several feature modules in Angular.
Each of the modules has its own navigation, so when navigating to one of the components of the feature module, this navigation should be loaded:

```
- Root
-- Feature Module 1
    Component 1 <-- Load navigation for Module 1
    Component 2 <-- Load navigation for Module 1
    Component 3 <-- Load navigation for Module 1
-- Feature Module 2
    Component 1 <-- Load navigation for Module 2
    Component 2 <-- Load navigation for Module 2
    Component 3 <-- Load navigation for Module 2
```

So I could execute a function to load the navigation in each "OnInit" of all components.

But this seems to be cumbersome to me.
I would like to find a way to execute an action for all components below a certain route.

But the features of Angular that I know seem not to be the right ones.

1. Idea: Guards

Guards are executed on routes and I could create a guard that executes on all child routes of Feature Module 1.
But this would be wrong, because Guards are not made for this. They should rather "protect" a route than execute some default action.

2. Idea: Resolvers

Resolvers are there to load data before a the components of certain routes are rendered. So they are also executed before, but I would still misuse this concept.

Or would I?

How would you tackle my problem?

Comment: Even though you have to implement in every component, I find inheritance as the most lexically correct solution. What do you think? I'm assuming you are not using `Standalone Components` and [`ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45970) is not suited for your case